# It only add 1 item in my recyclerview, is there someone who can figure it out?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I decide to use RecyclerView from android but it only show my 1 item, i don t know why. I make an individual resource file for design, my recyclerview is in fragment resource. I will post my code so you cand help me out. I mention i use an adapter class for my recyclerview then I from the class DataModel where i declare all the variables, then i use them in my Adaptor class and then it suppose to add items in recycler view by the code in the fragment using add(datamodel).

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
                android:padding="16dp">
        
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />
        
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is header"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
                    android:text="Desciere"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>
        
        
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
    I use an Adapter:
    
        package com.example.serviceapp;
        
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        
        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
        
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        
        public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>
        {
            ArrayList<DataModel> dataholder;
        
            public Adapter(ArrayList<DataModel> dataholder) {
                this.dataholder = dataholder;
            }
        
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_design,parent,false);
                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                holder.img.setImageResource(dataholder.get(position).getImage());
                holder.header.setText(dataholder.get(position).getHeader());
                holder.desc.setText(dataholder.get(position).getDesc());
            }
        
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return dataholder.size();
            }
        
            class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            {
                ImageView img;
                TextView header,desc;
        
                public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
                    header = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
                    desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
                }
            }
        
        }
    
    There is my Fragment:
    
    package com.example.serviceapp;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ArrayList<DataModel> dataholder;
    
    
        public HomeFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recview);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            dataholder= new ArrayList<>();
    
    
            DataModel ob1= new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_action_oil,"Ulei","Acest martor indica un nivel redus de ulei.");
            dataholder.add(ob1);
    
            DataModel ob2 = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_action_lichid, "Lichid de parbriz","Acest martor indica un nivel scazut al lichidului de parbriz.");
            dataholder.add(ob2);
    
    
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(dataholder));
            return view;
        }
    }
    
    And this is my resource file for fragment where is my RecyclerView:
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".HomeFragment"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">
    
        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="91dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="296dp" />
    
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

package com.example.serviceapp;

public class DataModel
{
    int image;
    String header, desc;

    public DataModel(int image, String header, String desc) {
        this.image = image;
        this.header = header;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `CardView`. I think you missed check about it. You are using `match_parent` instead `wrap_content` . So the size will cover up all the size of phone. Because of that, it will display one item.

Change your `CardView` to this.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was reading about a same problem but they talk about RelativeLayout instead of CardView. I was focusing on the wrong part, thank you so much again.

Comment: @DariusMan you can tick right as the correct answer if this answered your question